# Oracle Foreign Key

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

I get the following error when I try to add a foreign key to my purchaseorderheader table :

ORA-02270: "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"

[image]

I made sure the table and column names are the same but I still get the error, any ideas?

Comment: Your table design seems a bit odd. It looks like you ought to have a `purchaseorder` table with a PK of `purchaseorderid`, and then make that column in both `purchaseorderdetail` and `purchaseorderheader` be an FK to that parent table. That would allow multiple detail records per purchase order.

Answer (score 1):

You have a composite primary key that is composed of two columns but, in your foreign key, you are only referencing one of the columns of the composite primary key and not the entire primary key.

You either need to:

- change the primary key to be only on the single column `purchaseorderid`;
- keep the existing primary key and additionally create a `UNIQUE` key on only the `purchaseorderid` column of the first table; or
- include both columns of the primary key in the foreign key.

Whichever option you choose, you should make sure that it implements the business logic that you are trying to capture in the table; if it does not then you should revisit the database-design and find a design that does capture your business logic.

Comment: I put purchaseorderdetailid in UNIQUE and it works, thanks!

Comment: @Max It may "work" but you need to make sure that that is the correct design for your table and it implements the logic that you are intending. If it does not then you may need to revisit the database design.

Comment: @Max,  PurchaseOrderDetail table having composite key (purchaseorderid, purchaseorderdetailid). If you are adding UNIQUE constraint to purchaseorderdetailid column then in the current design, are you expecting duplicate value in purchaseorderid column. 
If purchaseorderid column will not holds duplicate values, then you can set primary key to only purchaseorderid column